# Use Thin LVM Volume for KVM VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt, qemu, thin

I now we cannot use thin LVM volumes with libvirt. Is there any other alternative allowing use of LVM thin provisioning in KVM/QEMU virtual machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libvirt` does not directly support using thin volumes as storage pool: when selecting the volume group where creating each logical volumes (disk images), the thin pool is not shown on the list.

To use thin volumes with `libvirt`, you have two possibility:

- manually create the required thin volume, attaching it to the virtual machine;
- otherwise, you can create a single big thin volume, formatting it with XFS, mounting it and using libvirt to create a directory-based storage pool (creating VM disk images as plain file on the XFS filesystem).

Comment: "attaching it to the virtual machine". Do you mean during create the VM with virt-install? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I mean by directly specifing the required thin volume in the xml file (or using a GUI as `virt-manager` to edit it)

Comment: When I edit xml and try to run the VM via Cockpit, I get an error. For virt-manager, I can't even see the volume.

Comment: In `virt-manager` you should be able to select "browse local" and to manually select the right logical volume. Otherwise, you have to edit the domain xml file.

Comment: I can't see any "browse local" option. All I can do is choose "Select or create custom storage" then select the pool. In the LVM pool only fat LVM volumes are listed.

Comment: You should have a "Browse local" button as per this [image](https://www.berrange.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/14-virt-manager-choose-lun.png)

Comment: I finally found it. In fact, I have a recent version of virt-manager installed on remote computer, and "browse local" is not in the same place as on the screenshot. The button is disabled because I am on a remote computer and I believe it will be enabled if I use virt-manager locally on the server side. @shodanshok: Thank you very much for you help.